# How to start Jupyter Console without colors?

Tags: python, ipython, readline, jupyter, jupyter-console

`jupyter console --colors=NoColor` makes `In [x]:` and `Out [x]:` colorless but any error messages are still colored.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to set `c.InteractiveShell.colors` in the [IPython kernel config](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/options/kernel.html) file. The colours in error messages are generated by the kernel, not the console frontend.